# Read different values out of list with same class list items

Tags: html, ruby, list, watir

How is it possible to get specific values from list items with the same list class with Watir?

I'm using Watir in Ruby. The html of the list looks like this:

```html
<li class="CLASSNAME">
      <div class="DIV1">
        <div class="DIV2">
          <div class="DIV3">
            <div class="DIV4">
            <a class="HYPERLINK_CLASSNAME" title="TITLE"> ... </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div> 
    </li> 

<li class="CLASSNAME">
      <div class="DIV1">
        <div class="DIV2">
          <div class="DIV3">
            <div class="DIV4">
            <a class="HYPERLINK_CLASSNAME" title="TITLE2"> ... </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div> 
    </li>
```

If I want to get the values for TITLE and TITLE2 separately, how am I able to let Watir manage this? Everything except the title values are the exact same values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate the lists as shown below

```
p browser.lis.map{|li|li.a.title}
```

Output

```
["TITLE", "TITLE2"]
```

With the given Html structure, you can simply iterate the link and print the title as shown below

```
p browser.as.map(&:title)
```